# Apply css to an input without affecting its value

Tags: css

I have the following css

And I want the input styled but its value to remanin unstyled.

```css
input[type=text] {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
  border-left: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  font-size: 27px;
  animation-name: spin;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="timeInput" id="time" class="time1" readonly>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You cannot see whether it's styled or not. Because there's no clue to see what is styled such as background or content.
2. If you want to apply animation css, you need to set keyframes to animate.

```css
@keyframes spin {
  from {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
  }
  to {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
  }
}

input[type=text] {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
  border-left: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  font-size: 27px;
  animation-name: spin;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="timeInput" id="time" class="time1" readonly value="Foo bar">
```